# Field theory: an equality involving the number of homomorphisms from an extension $E$ of $F$ to $\overline{F}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

First some notation.  Let $F$ be a field, $E$ an algebraic extension of $F$ and $\overline{F}$ the algebraic closure of $F$.  Let $\{E:F\}$ represents the number of non-zero homomorphisms from $E$ to $\overline{F}$ which leave the field $F$ fixed.

Suppose we have a tower of fields:

$F \subset E \subset K$

How can it be shown that $\{K:F\} = \{K:E\}*\{E:F\}$?

I know of a similar equality that deals with degrees of field extensions, but here we're talking about functions that go from $E$ to a much larger field $\overline{F}$ which makes it seem hard to visualize.  What can I do to prove this?

Comment: "The closure"?? The algebraic, the separable, the normal...what *closure*?

Comment: The field in which every polynomial with coeff's in F splits, the algebraic closure.

Comment: So let me see if I understood, and maybe you could explain this in your question: we have F\subset E\;$ (not necessarily *an algebraic extension*, as far as I can read), and $\;\overline F\;$ is an (or the, as you wish) algebraic closure of $\;F\;$. Would the extension in fact be algebraic in order the equality you want to prove is true?

Comment: Yes, I will add those details.  I didn't think to initially because we haven't really worked with non algebraic extensions.

Comment: This is proved in Lang's *Algebra*. By the way, a homomorphism of fields is automatically non-zero because it maps $1$ to $1$.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg I think I might have access to that book, do you know the page/section number?

Comment: Chapter V, §4, Theorem 4.1, page 239 .

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, it depends on a strategy like this, modulo suitable care to the hypotheses:
If $k\subset L$ are fields and $\psi\colon L\to\Omega$, where $\psi$ is a field morphism and  $\Omega$ is an algebraically closed field, then $\{L:k\}=\{\psi(L):\psi(k)\}$. This needs a proof, but it isn’t hard.